# C# draw line graph with points from file

Tags: c#, linegraph

I've program, which gets temperature of processor and HDD, and show me:

- CPU$Intel Core i5-4440$CPU Core #1 30°C
- CPU$Intel Core i5-4440$CPU Core #2 47°C
- CPU$Intel Core i5-4440$CPU Core #3 43°C
- CPU$Intel Core i5-4440$CPU Core #4 45°C
- CPU$Intel Core i5-4440$CPU Package 47°C
- HDD$ST1000DM003-1ER162$Temperature 35°C

Program is refreshed every 5 seconds and temperature saved to a file:

- 30
- 47
- 43
- 45
- 47
- 35

After 5 sekund new temperatures are save the next line in the same file.

Now I must draw graph line for each element separately, for example the CPU Intel Core i5-4440 $ $ CPU core # 1: 30, 31, 30, 40, 35, and move these parameters on the line graph.

Comment: OK, so whats the question?

Comment: How to do it? Save every point to table?

Comment: thats not what stackoverflow is for - we are here to help you debug your code.. theres a ton of  ways, pick one, try it

Comment: Did you check out the Chart control? It seems just what you want. One Series per cpu, Charttype=Line and add points as they come in..

Comment: using datavisualization dll,try to draw a line graph.